# Accessing android camera using BitWebServer (PHP)

Tags: php, android, scripting, camera

Does anyone know of an easy way to grab an image from an android camera using the PHP engine built into [BitWebServer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andi.serverweb&hl=en)? I suppose if need be, I can write an android app and make a sys call but I was wondering if there might be an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it using PHP. PHP is a script interpreter running server side, it cannot interact with the camera hardware on an android device.

Creating a native Android app is the way to go. Performance will also be many times better using native code rather some other workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I hear tell there may be some ways to do it from various scripts in OS 3.0 and above, but it's through the OS itself. I did manage to find a rather popular web-cam software that will provide it's own mini-web server though for doing video (mpeg style) streaming as well as a number of image formats. That should suffice fine for what I'm doing which is mainly going to be novelty only. I'll just have to fire up both apps when goofing around.

(I have been trying to find a cell provider or some other means to connect to the internet when camping way back in the woods of northern Michigan. I was thinking it might be cute to post a 'camp cam' to a short list of friends to see if whatever connection I get is accessible from the outside)